# Restcomm Demo Call Failed

Tags: sip, voip, mobicents, restcomm

I have autoconfigured restcomm with the network details.

Now when I am trying to call sip:1234@host:5080
I have checked all the other demos and all of them are failing. I tried changing the cache folder to an external folder on the disk even it is not working. I have tried the Tomcat version in Windows, tried executing the demo calls , it is throwing OutOfMemoryException.

The error log from Restcomm is,

```
2015-06-17 15:02:16,943 INFO  [Play] (Thread-1) Received URL can not be found , firing of
2015-06-17 15:02:16,944 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=2 Started, message= NTFY mobicents/ivr/1@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:02:16,944 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483656 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:02:16,948 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=2 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:02:16,967 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483654 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:02:17,025 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483658 Started, message= DLCX mobicents/bridge/1@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:02:17,029 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483658 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:02:17,046 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483659 Started, message= DLCX mobicents/bridge/1@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:02:17,048 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483659 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:02:17,126 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483660 Started, message= DLCX mobicents/ivr/1@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:02:17,127 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483660 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:02:17,205 INFO  [Server] (Thread-1) Global hearbeat is still alive
2015-06-17 15:03:17,206 INFO  [Server] (Thread-2) Global hearbeat is still alive
2015-06-17 15:04:17,205 INFO  [Server] (Thread-1) Global hearbeat is still alive
2015-06-17 15:04:44,686 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483661 Started, message= CRCX mobicents/bridge/$@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:04:44,689 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483661 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:04:44,725 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483662 Started, message= CRCX mobicents/bridge/2@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:04:44,727 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483662 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:04:44,745 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483663 Started, message= MDCX mobicents/ivr/2@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:04:44,746 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483663 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:04:44,766 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483664 Started, message= RQNT mobicents/ivr/2@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:04:44,785 INFO  [Play] (Thread-2) (mobicents/ivr/2) Start announcement (segment=0)
2015-06-17 15:04:44,790 ERROR [AudioPlayerImpl] (Thread-2) (mobicents/ivr/2) error occured
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://33.33.33.34:8080/restcomm/cache/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/ef992228519164b96cd28beb01cf5e54fb9b51cab8b2c13c2067edbf8c10679e.wav
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.impl.resource.mediaplayer.audio.wav.WavTrackImpl.<init>(WavTrackImpl.java:74)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.impl.resource.mediaplayer.audio.AudioPlayerImpl.setURL(AudioPlayerImpl.java:150)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.mgcp.pkg.au.Play.startAnnouncementPhase(Play.java:162)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.mgcp.pkg.au.Play.execute(Play.java:115)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.mgcp.controller.Request.execute(Request.java:142)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.mgcp.tx.cmd.NotificationRequestCmd$Executor.perform(NotificationRequestCmd.java:213)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.scheduler.Task.run(Task.java:122)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.scheduler.Scheduler$WorkerThread.run(Scheduler.java:420)
2015-06-17 15:04:44,791 INFO  [Play] (Thread-2) Received URL can not be found , firing of
2015-06-17 15:04:44,792 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=3 Started, message= NTFY mobicents/ivr/2@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:04:44,792 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483664 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:04:44,792 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=3 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:04:44,806 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483666 Started, message= DLCX mobicents/bridge/2@33.33.33.34:2427, call agent = /33.33.33.34:2727
2015-06-17 15:04:44,807 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483666 was executed normaly
2015-06-17 15:05:17,205 INFO  [Server] (Thread-1) Global hearbeat is still alive
2015-06-17 15:06:17,205 INFO  [Server] (Thread-1) Global hearbeat is still alive
```

Answer (score 1):

You should better try to run Restcomm using the Docker image as described here: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/gvagenas/restcomm/

George

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on OpenStack or Amazon ? 
Is 33.33.33.34 IP Address and port 8080 accessible from within the machine itself as it looks like the wav file located at http://33.33.33.34:8080/restcomm/cache/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/ef992228519164b96cd28beb01cf5e54fb9b51cab8b2c13c2067edbf8c10679e.wav can't be found by Restcomm, you can also verify it is actually present in the cache folder of Restcomm $restcomm_home/standalone/deployments/restcomm.war/cache folder

Also did you configure the following below in restcomm.conf ?

#PUBLIC IP ADDRESS

STATIC_ADDRESS=

Comment: It is running on my localbox. The wav file is not created in the cache folder. I have added the STATIC_ADDRESS too.